# Jenkins - SSH deployment issue - not able to delete files in target folder except one directory

Tags: bash, jenkins, pipeline

I am trying to auto deploy the angular build files to server using SHH and Jenkins.

In the deployment folder, I have a directory 'app2' which should not be deleted.

I wanted to remove the existing files in the target folder (/var/www/html) except the folder 'app2'.

But I get the following error while deploying,

```
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [cd /var/www/html && shopt -s extglob && rm -rf !(app2) && mv /var/tmp/MyApp/* /var/www/html] ...
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `cd /var/www/html && shopt -s extglob && rm -rf !(app2) && mv /var/tmp/MyApp/* /var/www/html'
```

I feel that there is something wrong with this statement,

```
shopt -s extglob && rm -rf !(app2)
```

What would be the solution to fix the above issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Bash parses the command line before the `shopt` gets executed.

A common workaround is to split it across two physical lines, so that the first one gets parsed *and executed* before the second.

Minimal demo:

```sh
bash -c 'shopt -s extglob
echo !(app)'
```

The newline is crucial; if you replace it with a semicolon, you get the error you are reporting.

If you don't want to or can't do that, perhaps use `find` instead.

```sh
find /var/www/html \! -path '/var/www/html/app2/*' -delete
```